# RestSharp posting ByteArray / Stream data

Tags: c#, rest, arrays, multipartform-data, restsharp

trying to post a byte array or memory stream with RestSharp.

I have tried the following

```
request.AddFile("stream", x => new MemoryStream(blocks.First().Value), "stream", "application/binary");
```

And

```
request.AddFile("stream", blocks.First().Value, "stream", "application/binary");
```

Where `blocks.First().Value` is a Byte Array

On the server end I am expecting a form with stream parameter in it that I can extract the bytes from.

Additional information:
Adding null or string.Empty to AddFile sends the byte array

```
request.AddFile("stream", blocks.First().Value, string.Empty);
```

The problem is that it adds 2 bytes to each byte array sent (1 for carriage return and one for new line). And I cannot remove them on every post on server side since other clients do not behave this way.

Thank you for any input on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it with a pull request in Nancy 0.11 so this is no longer an issue.